# Python does not solve equation with previously calculated variable

Tags: python, equation

I am trying to solve a simple equation but when I insert a previously calculated variable ("g_th" in this case), python stops working. Even if I hit the stop red button, spyder console is frozen. When, however, I use g_th = any number, then python solves the equation.
Thank you for the help in advance.

------Code below------

```
from sympy import symbols, solve, log, sqrt

L = 500e-4
R1 = R2 = 0.3
alpha = 6.38
Gamma = 0.08
n_tr = 1e16
g0 = 1800

alpha_m = (1/L)*log(1/(sqrt(R1*R2)))

g_th = (alpha_m + alpha)/Gamma

n_th = symbols('n_th')
eq2 = g0*log(n_th/n_tr) - g_th
sol = solve(eq2)
print(sol)
```

Comment: What does happen when you CTRL+C the code? Is it possible that the number is so big that the IDE keeps calculating it? It looks like the 'solve' function is the culprit of the behaviour to me...

Comment: CTRL+C does not work, nothing really happens. I have tried to use "eq2 = g0*log(n_th/n_tr) - 380" where 380 is the result of g_th, and it works. But somehow, when I use the variable name (g_th), python does not solve the equation